# Solvable? $f(x)=\tan(\frac{a\pi x}{b})+c$ has consecutive asymptotes at $x=-1.5$ and $x=-0.7$, and passes through $(-3,3.5)$. Find $a$, $b$, $c$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A friend believes that a 'question' he has set is solvable, but I'm arguing that it is in not in any way. He won't give me the answer or more information, but I was hoping for a second opinion. This is the exact wording that he gave me:

> A function of the form $$f(x) = \tan \left(\frac{a \pi x}{b} \right) + c$$ has consecutive asymptotes at $x=-1.5$ and $x=-0.7$ and passes through the point $(-3,3.5)$. Find the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

What do you reckon? I'd love it if you could show the answer

My argument is that if there is no horizontal translation, then the point where x=0 has to be exactly half way in between 2 asymptotes. However, he has stated that .1.5 and -0.7 are consecutive asymptotes, and thus the period of the function has to be 0.8. If we take this to be true, then 0 is not half way between the two asymptotes: -0.7 and 0.1. That's my reasoning for the question, that you need a horizontal translation.

Comment: Can you provide your argument that the question is not solvable?

Comment: Please include your own thoughts on the problem, to help others avoid wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know, duplicating your effort, or using techniques with which you are not yet familiar.

Comment: @theyaoster My argument is that if there is no horizontal translation, then the point where x=0 has to be exactly half way in between 2 asymptotes. However, he has stated that .1.5 and -0.7 are consecutive asymptotes, and thus the period of the function has to be 0.8. If we take this to be true, then 0 is not half way between the two asymptotes: -0.7 and 0.1. That's my reasoning for the question, that you need a horizontal translation. I'll also add this info to the original question

Comment: Clearly, when $x=0$ we have $f(x) = c$. Did you mean $y=0$? I'm not quite sure what you're trying to get at.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I 100% agree, but I've not been given the value of the tangent at f(0), so the idea that f(x)=c does not aid the result. I still mean that when x=0, as in when the function crosses the y-intercept, that it has to be exactly half way between the two asymptotes that are closest to it.

Comment: @T.Duncan: Your argument is sound.

Comment: @Blue coolio, if you agree that the question is unsolvable in its current form I'd consider this question answered. Thanks dude!

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem proved to be unsolvable, thanks to aid from Blue, Fimpellizieri and theyaoster. Thanks guys!

As to why, My argument is that if there is no horizontal translation, then the point where x=0 has to be exactly half way in between 2 asymptotes. However, he has stated that .1.5 and -0.7 are consecutive asymptotes, and thus the period of the function has to be 0.8. If we take this to be true, then 0 is not half way between the two asymptotes: -0.7 and 0.1. That's my reasoning for the question, that you need a horizontal translation.